# PHP: array with empty value gives error in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, empty-list

For this example, when I call the variable `$my_settings`, the output would look like this:

```
Array (
    [personal_options] => Array (
            [rich_editing] => rich_editing
            [admin_color] => admin_color
            [comment_shortcuts] => comment_shortcuts
            [admin_bar_front] => admin_bar_front
        )
    [name] => Array (
            [nickname] => nickname
        )
    [contact_info] => Array (
            [url] => url
        )
    [about_yourself] => Array (
            [description] => description
        )
    [yoast_seo] => 
)
```

When I run a `foreach` loop, get everyone's favorite "**Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**" error because this array has `[yoast_seo] =>`, which is empty and throwing it off.

Currently my `foreach` is set up as the following:

```
$my_settings = get_option( 'dsbl_profile_settings' );

if ( is_array( $my_settings ) || is_object( $my_settings ) ) {
    foreach ( $my_settings as $group => $item ) {
        foreach ( $item as $value ) {
            echo '<pre>'; print_r( $value ); echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I already use the `is_array()` and `is_object()` check in my loop. My guess is that I need to also perform a check to see if it's empty as well before it runs `[yoast_seo] =>`? I'm at a loss on the best way to implement that since I've tried the following in my `if` statement:

```
if ( is_array( $profile_fields ) || is_object( $profile_fields ) || isset( $profile_fields ) ) { // Attempt #1

if ( ( is_array( $profile_fields ) || is_object( $profile_fields ) ) && isset( $profile_fields ) ) { // Attempt #2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have nested foreach and you are providing an empty variable, you should check if the variable is array before passing.

```
if ( is_array( $my_settings ) || is_object( $my_settings ) ) {
    foreach ( $my_settings as $group => $item ) {
        if(is_array($item)) {
            foreach ( $item as $value ) {
                echo '<pre>'; print_r( $value ); echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, so I was checking at the wrong level for the empty variable. Thanks for pointing that out and clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You have checked `is_array( $my_settings )` for `$my_settings`, which is correct. But what about `foreach ( $item as $value )`?

Your error is there for the group level loop. Not for `$my_settings`.

So if you do

```
if ( is_array( $my_settings ) || is_object( $my_settings ) ) {
    foreach ( $my_settings as $group => $item ) {
        if ( !empty($item) && (is_array( $item ) || is_object( $item )) ) {
            foreach ( $item as $value ) {
                echo '<pre>'; print_r( $value ); echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it should work. Basically same condition that you are checking for `$my_settings`.

Hope this helps you!